# Java Gson .add function not taking String parameter (maven project)

Tags: java, maven, gson

So this is a very very weird bug I'm having in intellij where if I instantiate a JsonArray (in the gson library), it only has one .add method that requires a JsonElement as it's parameter.

```
JsonArray foo = new JsonArray();

for (String bar : this.baz) {
    foo.add(bar); // .add throws this error: java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to com.google.gson.JsonElement
}
```

btw this is a maven repository using the following gson dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>LATEST</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Which version of gson do you actually use?

Comment: @jreznot using 2.8.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `add()` requires `JsonElement` then use:

```
foo.add(new JsonPrimitive(bar))
```

Gson 2.8.2 provides overload versions of `add()` that receive simple String.

Comment: this worked, thanks. though, why would this be the case? I tried doing this in Eclipse and .add worked with strings and most primitive types.

Comment: It could be the problem with IDE. Do you see the problem as compiler error or just IDE warning?